# Create a user and add all roles using the rolify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a system that is set up using devise and rolify to manage users, however, I need to create a method where I can do something like the following:

```
[14] pry(main)> User.create_owner(username:"test", name:"Testing", password:"Password-1", password_confirmation:"Password-1", email: 'testing@hey.com')
```

that creates a user and gives the user all of the roles that I have in the system.

So far I have the following

```rb
def self.create_owner(options)
  user = self.new(options)

  @roles.each do |role, user|
    user.add_role?(role[:name])
  end

  user.has_role? :default
  user.save
end
```

but this is what I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
from /home/ben/code/BusinessCloudEssential/app/models/user.rb:291:in `create_owner'
```

All of the roles have been created using a seeds file and are in the database following Rolify docs.

**EDIT**
OK so I now have the following

```rb
def self.create_owner(options)
  user = self.new(options)

  Role.all.each do
    user.roles = Role.all
  end
  
  user.has_role? :default
  user.save
end
```

and the following output

```
[1] pry(main)> User.create_owner(username:"test", name:"testing", password:"Password-1", password_confirmation:"Password-1", email: 'testing@hey.com')
  Role Load (2.6ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'ben.bagley1@hey.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'ben1' LIMIT 1
  User Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'ben.bagley1@hey.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
  Setting Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'number_of_users' LIMIT 1
  Setting Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'number_of_users' LIMIT 1
  TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
TypeError: compared with non class/module
from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:108:in `>='
```

```
TypeError: compared with non class/module
from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/relation
```

Comment: `@rolls` is not set maybe you were looking for `Role.all`? that being said 1) should `add_role?` be `add_role` 2) Wouldn't `user.roles= Role.all` work?

Comment: I'll update the code @engineersmnky I'm getting `TypeError: compared with non class/module` now

Comment: I didn't mean both. Either `Role.all.each {|role| user.add_role(role)}` or `user.roles = Rolls.all` (which I was unsure about). Also this line `user.has_role? :default` does not do anything